# Extract value in filename with Camel

Tags: java, xml, apache-camel, dsl

I would like to extract a value from a filename in Camel, here's a simplified route I'm using :

```
<camel:route id="myBatchRoute">
<camel:from uri="file:${batch.repTmp}?include=UMU_BATCH_Management_.*.xml&amp;move=${batch.repArchive}" />
<camel:to uri="bean:batch?method=process" />
</camel:route>
```

The value I want to extract is in the REGEX's incude : **.*.**

I need to extract this value to create an other file.

If someone have an idea how to deal with it ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have the actual file name in a header with the key CamelFileName. You can then run a reg exp on this String value to grab that piece you need.

Comment: I see what you mean, but this is the syntax I don't see.

Comment: What do you mean? You would have to run your own reg exp with UMU_BATCH_Management_.*.xml against the actual file name you can find in that header.

Comment: I mean, I can't find how to transfer the variable from the name file (consumer) into the new name file (producer).

Comment: See about bean parameter binding: http://camel.apache.org/bean-binding.html and http://camel.apache.org/parameter-binding-annotations.html

Comment: Just forget to say, I need to resolved this only with Spring XML, no Java. (sorry)

Comment: Yeah read those links and you can get further how to bind the CamelFileName header to a parameter in the bean method signature